# Move styles from twig include into parent template

Tags: templates, twig, symfony

I am working on a relatively large app with hundreds of twig templates and includes. Consider the following simplified structure:

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

_

```
{# view.html.twig #}
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block head %}
    {# this will go into the head of the document and works fine #}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'include.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

_

```
{# include.html.twig #}
<style>
  /* 
    I want this style block appear in the head of the document (layout.html.twig).
    Using {% block head %} is not an option, as this code is evaluated later than the head block is flushed
  */
  {{ generate_minified_css_here() }}
</style>

<!-- rest of included content -->
```

I want to make sure that whenever I `include` a template, the styles are included as well. Due to the amount of styles and templates, generating a one big css file is not an option.

In the past I handled this by using the `scoped` style tag and it all validated perfectly, even though the styles were not actually "scoped" by most browsers. Since recently, W3C no longer accepts scoped styles.

My question is: How do I get the styles from `include.html.twig` into `layout.html.twig` head section?

Comment: With your current setup you can't have `include.html.twig` *manipulate* `layout.html.twig` because included files are included as strings. Meaning the included template is rendered fully first and only then the result is placed in the including file.

Comment: @Karolis What was your solution? I have a very similar problem in a large web project where we only want to include the styles and javascript files which are really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

And what about split your `include.html` template and get this structure?:

```
{% block head %}
    {% include 'include-style.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% include 'include.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

-

```
{# include-style.html.twig #}
<style>
  /* 
    I want this style block appear in the head of the document (layout.html.twig).
    Using {% block head %} is not an option, as this code is evaluated later than the head block is flushed
  */
  {{ generate_minified_css_here() }}
</style>
```

-

```
{# include.html.twig #}    
<!-- included content without style content -->
```

Comment: I could split the `include.html.twig`, yes.  The problem is that there might be some complicated logic inside the view body. It may include a file depending on the value of some variable. The included file may include other 'sub-includes' and so on. If I go this way, I would have to copy all the logic from the body to the head as well, which isn't very efficient. Also, if I decide to remove the include within body, I will almost certainly forget to remove the include within head.